# OANDA Deprecated REST API

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

As a means of learning the very basics of algorithmic trading and [OANDA](https://www.oanda.com/us-en/), I found [a tutorial](https://www.oreilly.com/content/algorithmic-trading-in-less-than-100-lines-of-python-code/) on how to make a very basic trading algorithm to "practice" algorithmic trading. The only issue is that the tutorial uses OANDA's v1 REST API, whereas it now uses v20 REST API.

The Python module `oandapyV20` seems to have replaced `oandapy`, and it seems like there are methods that have become deprecated in the newest module. For example, on line #7 of the tutorial, it uses a method called `get_history`, and that seems to be totally deprecated now from what I can tell.

My question is, what could I do to replace the `get_history` method in particular, and are there any other sections of the code in the tutorial that someone who is familiar with the OANDA v20 REST API might see that are also going to be problematic/need to be totally reworked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I found some example code [here](https://oanda-api-v20.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/instruments/instrumentlist.html) that may be of use:

```
import oandapyV20
>>> import oandapyV20.endpoints.instruments as instruments
>>> client = oandapyV20.API(access_token=...)
>>> params = ...
>>> r = instruments.InstrumentsCandles(instrument="DE30_EUR",
>>>                                    params=params)
>>> client.request(r)
>>> print r.response
```

Therefore I would edit the tutorial as follows:

```
import oandapyV20
import oandapyV20.endpoints.instruments as instruments
oanda = oandapyV20.API(access_token=...)
params = {'start': '2016-12-08', 
          'end': '2016-12-10', 
          'granularity': 'M1'}
data = instruments.InstrumentsCandles(instrument='EUR_USD', params=params)
oanda.request(data)
print(data.response)
```

As I don't have a token to test, I am not sure what parameters are required for the new api, but hopefully this helps!

**Edit #2**:
So I got about this far, but this documentation uses *iPython* and `%matplotlib inline` which I'm unfamiliar with.  I couldn't quite get it all to work but this is where I'm at.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np                                                              

import oandapyV20
import oandapyV20.endpoints.pricing as pricing
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()                                                

TOKEN = #<oauth_token>
IDENT = #<accountID>
oanda = oandapyV20.API(access_token=TOKEN)
params = {
    'instruments': 'EUR_USD,EUR_JPY',
    'since': '2016-12-10',
    'granularity': 'M1'
}
data = pricing.PricingInfo(accountID=IDENT, params=params)
oanda.request(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data.response['prices']).set_index('time')

df['closeoutAsk'].astype(float)

df['returns'] = np.log(float(df['closeoutAsk'][1]) / float(df['closeoutAsk'].shift(1)[1]))         

cols = []                                                                       
for momentum in [15, 30, 60, 120]:                                              
    col = f'position_{momentum}'                                                
    df[col] = np.sign(df['returns'].rolling(momentum).mean())                   
    cols.append(col)                                                            

strats = ['returns']                                                            
for col in cols:
    strat = f'strategy_{col.split("_")[1]}'                                    
    df[strat] = df[col].shift(1) * df['returns']                               
    strats.append(strat)                                                       

ts = df[strats]
ts = ts.cumsum()
plt.figure(); ts.plot(); plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Feel free to take a run at it.

Comment: I appreciate this answer a lot, and it definitely helped me get past those few lines that were causing me issues before, but I'm afraid that the API has just changed so much now that most of the code would need to be completely reworked. I might be better off just starting fresh and using this tutorial as more of a general guideline. As soon as I implemented your fix I immediately had issues only a few lines later, and after hacking together a fix for that line, there was another error right around the corner.

Comment: Feel free to create an account here: https://www.oanda.com/demo-account/login btw if you're curious yourself on how everything works. The reason I was planning on using this service, in particular, is because it allows for the use of 'fake money' that you can use to trade with real-world equities, so it's a totally free way to screw around with the stock market as much as you want. It's a pretty good practice tool for algorithmic trading I think. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: @BobSmith I tell you what, if you're not in a super hurry I've got some time today that I might just give it a go. I don't know much about trading, but I reckon I can rework the tutorial a bit while learning something along the way.

Comment: Yeah feel free to if you're motivated. I will probably get around to "fixing" this tutorial eventually, but I really don't know how long it will take me and I might just end up doing something totally new as I said earlier. I'd be happy to have other code to look at if you're going to try your hand. It definitely doesn't help that I have limited experience in pandas as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [History instrument](https://developer.oanda.com/rest-live/rates/#retrieveInstrumentHistory) via the `candles`